# How dangerous are kettlebells?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, injury-prevention, kettlebell

I never paid much attention to kettlebells until I saw a video that said they have numerous advantages over traditional dumbells.

Swinging weights around as was demonstrated in the video looks dangerous.  Are there any studies assessing the number of injuries incurred as a result of using them?

Comment: Not really enough for an answer, (Mostly because a lot of studies haven't been done), but there is a slight (Stiatistically insignificant) increase from 5 to 9 injuries per 1000 hours of training - https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/46869/how-dangerous-are-kettlebells

Comment: Everything is dangerous when you don't know how to use it. Have you seen bench press and squat injuries? I know a guy that got hurt with an elastic band...